# How does the php snippet work?

Tags: php

```
 $this->_config = parse_ini_file($configIniFile);
```

And this is the content of `$configIniFile`：

```
; <?php exit; ?> DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
[database]
host                 = localhost
username             = root
password             = 
dbname               = openslopeone
port                 = 3306
adapter              = PDO_MYSQL ; PDO_MYSQL or MYSQLI
```

Comment: Its generally better to put configuration files _out_ of the web root if possible. However, the line exists to tell PHP to exit if the configuration file itself is requested by a browser (thus not revealing super secret database information)

Comment: It might be helpful, however, if you actually asked the question. The snippet itself is not 'self evident'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

It simply declares the configuration from an ini file within an array.

The exit function exists, so the configuration file cannot be read directly from a browser, (with a leading ; to comment it out).

Answer (score 1):

The [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function parses a configuration file (much like the one you have above).  The ini file starts with a `<?php exit; ?>` to ensure that if the configuration file is loaded it won't execute any code.  The ini file you are using apparently defines SQL connection information.

Comment: Might be useful to say if the configuration file is requested (i.e. via http), php will just exit and not display the file contents.